# Identify 7-pin connector on PCB

Tags: pcb, identification, connector

I am new to electronics and need help identifying a 7-pin connector on an old circuit board for my dad’s Shasta trailer.

[image: Trailer Circuit Board]

Due to an existing broken trace that lies underneath, I tried to de-solder the part and fix the trace, but I have not been successful. At this point, I am ready to cut the component pins and remove it from the board.

[image: Close up]

Unfortunately, I am unable to locate a schematic for the circuit board and I cannot identify what type of voltage it can handle. I do know however that this circuit board gets most of its power from a 12 volt RV battery and sometimes through a 120 volt hookup system. To be clear, this circuit board is for an old RV trailer.

[image: Side image]

[image: Backside]

Comment: use google image search to compare your photo of connector to world. looks like a 1 row jtag I m not sure

Comment: Considering the lm7808 and it being auto I'm pretty sure that connector sees from 8V to max 14V.

Comment: One of (if not _the_) most important criteria for identification of connectors is dimensions and pitch. Please measure and include with your question.

Comment: Mike_D. - Hi, Since this question about identifying the connector is effectively a duplicate of the 2nd half of your [previous question](/questions/595123), I'm closing that question as a duplicate of this one. (The 1st half of that question (about the 7808 regulator) got answered effectively in comments, as far as I can tell, so there is nothing remaining active on that question.) In future, please don't repeat questions (or parts of them) on Stack Exchange. Here, the approach is to "edit questions to improve them". See [this](/help/no-one-answers) in the [help]. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you SamGibson for helping me realize that I should have modified my previous post. I will make sure in the future to first check out the help section to avoid any further mistakes. Mike D.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it could be a TE Connect 2-644803-7. Though for your purpose it may be easier to take that connector out and put 2 new connectors between the board and whatever it is being hooked up to.

[Spec Sheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=644803&DocType=Customer%20Drawing&DocLang=English)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you've overheated pins and melted the shroud, so they are not aligned properly. You may still be able to fix it by overheating and repositioning pins, but you may also inflict even more damage to PCB.

Measure the existing connector and compare to the datasheet @JTH828 suggested. If it fits then replace the connector carefully. To remove old one first cut the pins from behind, then desolder remaining stubs one by one, this way is simpler than trying to do them all at once.

Finally, if after soldering new connector in place you have some traces still damaged, do not try to fix them. For through-hole boards the easiest way to fix the trace is leave it alone and just solder a piece of wire between the pins of the components.

Comment: when you say to cut the pins from behind, are you referring to the back of the shroud where the pins extend out or the front bottom (where the pins extend through the circuit board) of the component? I am having a heck of a time of being able to cut one pin at a time.

Comment: I refer to the pin parts from where they coming out at the back of plastic connector body to the point where they coming into PCB. The parts are clearly visible on the first and third photos. They must be extremely easy to cut with basic cheap wire cutters, like [this](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00FZPDG1K/) or [this](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GR7QF63). They are often included for free with 3D printers.